# Normal distribution - Probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory, normal-distribution

The post office has to transport a large number of letters and packets daily.
The number of letters is distributed normally with $\mu_1=7300$ ans $\sigma_1=500$. 
For the independent number of packets we consider the normal distribution with $\mu_2=450$ and $\sigma_2=90$.

I want to calculate the probability that in a day at most $6500$ letters will be delivered.

I also want to calculate the probability that together more than $7500$ letters and packets have to be delivered in one day.

$$$$

I have done the following:

Let $X$ describe the number of letters and $Y$ the number of packets.

For the first one: 
The probability is equal to $$P(X\leq 6500)=\Phi \left (\frac{6500-\mu_1}{\sigma_1}\right )=\Phi \left (\frac{6500-7300}{500}\right )=\Phi \left (\frac{-800}{500}\right )=\Phi \left (-1,6\right )=0.05480$$ 
Is this correct?

For the second one: 
Do we want to calculate the probability $P(X+Y>7500)$ ? If yes, how could we do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $X$ and $Y$ are independent normals, their sum is also normally distributed. In particular $X+Y$ is normal with mean
$$
E(X+Y)=EX+EY=7300+450=7750
$$
and variance
$$
\text{Var}(X+Y)=\text{Var}{X}+\text{Var}{Y}=500^2+90
^2$$
as $X$ and $Y$ are independent. With this knowledge you can do a similar computation to compute $P(X+Y>7500)$ as you did for the first question.

For a proof see this wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_normally_distributed_random_variables).

Comment: Ah ok! So, do we have the following? \begin{align*}P(X+Y>7500)&=1-P(X+Y\leq 7500) \\ & =1-\Phi \left (\frac{7500-7750}{\sqrt{500^2+90^2}}\right ) \\ & =1-\Phi \left (\frac{-250}{\sqrt{258100}}\right ) \\ & =1-\Phi \left (\frac{-250}{508.04}\right ) \\ & =1-\Phi \left (-0.49\right ) \\ & =1-0.31207\\ & =0.68793  \end{align*}

Comment: @MaryStar Looks good to me.

Comment: Great! Tha first part is also correct, isn't it? $$$$ I have also an other question... If we two discrete random variables they show the length of a product which are produced by two machines. The normal length is 450 mm but there are some deviations. I have calculated the expected value for each machine, and both are equal to 450 mm. And it is asked which machine is more reliable. Since the expected value is at each machine the normal length 450 mm, do we have to check the probability $P(X=450)$ at each machine?

Comment: We have these information: http://www.directupload.net/file/d/4941/7kpx6kn4_jpg.htm

Comment: @MaryStar Find which of the two discrete random variables has a lower standard deviation.

Comment: Ok! Thank you very much!! :-)